# What is the use of ret in following program

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img1 = cv2.imread('p1.jpg')
img2 = cv2.imread('p2.jpg')

rows,cols,channels = img2.shape
roi = img1[0:rows,0:cols]

ret,img2gray = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
mask = cv2.threshold(img2gray,100,255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

cv2.imshow('mask',mask)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

If I remove the ret from the img2gray code line then following error will generate this ValueError

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "oc5.py", line 10, in <module>
    ret,img2gray = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: I think you are making a mistake here. `cv2.cvtColor()` returns only one vale. But on the other hand, `cv2.threshold()` returns two values. Please check it once again.

Answer (score 2):

cv2.cvtColor returns two values. Ret is just a dummy variable used to hold the first value